# Trying to add a Type to shorthand argument name in Swift closure

Tags: swift, closures

I have below snippet where compiler tells me: 
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context. I have tried adding [Term] before the !$0 and it didn't work, I also tried deconstructing the closure but !zip gives me a lot of trouble.  How can I fix this problem?

```
extension Statement : Equatable {}
func == (lhs: Statement, rhs: Statement) -> Bool {
  return lhs.terms.count == rhs.terms.count
    && !zip(lhs.terms, rhs.terms).contains { !$0.isEqualTo($1) }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the answer you wrote yourself I asume `Term` is equal to `Term` if and only if their property `value` is equal and the terms of a Statement are equally sorted

This works in playground with Swift 2

```
import UIKit

class Statement {
    var terms: [Term] = []
}

struct Term {
    var value: Int
}

extension Statement : Equatable {}
func == (lhs: Statement, rhs: Statement) -> Bool
{
    guard lhs.terms.count == rhs.terms.count else {
        return false
    }
    for case let tuple in zip(lhs.terms, rhs.terms) where tuple.0.value != tuple.1.value {
        return false
    }

    return true
}

let statement1 = Statement()
statement1.terms = [Term(value: 1), Term(value: 4), Term(value: 4)]

let statement2 = Statement()
statement2.terms = [Term(value: 1), Term(value: 4), Term(value: 4)]

print(statement1 == statement2 ? "They're equal" : "They're Not equal")

// prints They're equal
```

If you want to support unsorted terms inside `Statement`, it's important to have an id in `Term`, and that a Statement *cannot* have a repeated Therm, with those rules then this will work:

```
import UIKit

class Statement {
    var terms: [Term] = []
}

struct Term {
    var id: Int
}

extension Statement : Equatable {}
func == (lhs: Statement, rhs: Statement) -> Bool {
    guard lhs.terms.count == rhs.terms.count else {
        return false
    }
    for case let leftTerm in lhs.terms where !rhs.terms.contains({ leftTerm.id == $0.id }){
        return false
    }

    return true
}

let statement1 = Statement()
statement1.terms = [Term(id: 6), Term(id: 1), Term(id: 4)]

let statement2 = Statement()
statement2.terms = [Term(id: 1), Term(id: 4), Term(id: 6)]

print(statement1 == statement2 ? "They're equal" : "They're Not equal")

// prints They're equal
```

Hope it helped :D